# hasNextInt does not solve Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) { 

      int t;
      Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
      ScoreCalculation ob = new ScoreCalculation();
      t=ip.nextInt();
      ob.score(t); }
}

class ScoreCalculation {

  void score(int t)
  {  

    Scanner ipu=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,cum1=0,cum2=0,lead1=0,lead2=0,one,two;
     for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
       //if(ipu.hasNextInt())
       one=ipu.nextInt();
       //if(ipu.hasNextInt())
       two=ipu.nextInt();
       cum1+=one;
       cum2+=two;
       if(cum1>cum2)
       {
          if(lead1<(cum1-cum2))
          lead1=(cum1-cum2);

       }
       else
       {
       if(lead2<(cum2-cum1))
          lead2=(cum2-cum1); 
       }
    }
    if(lead1>lead2)
    System.out.println("1 "+lead1);
    else
    System.out.println("2 "+lead2);

  }
}
```

here is my code when i convert to hasNextInt it still shows error 
the TestClass name and use of two classes is must

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

    at ScoreCalculation.score(TestClass.java:20)

    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:9)
```

the error with hasint

```
TestClass.java:20: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

       one=ipu.hasNextInt();

                         ^

TestClass.java:22: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

       two=ipu.hasNextInt();
```

Comment: `hasNextInt()` returns a **boolean**. You need to check the return value *before* calling `nextInt()`.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use two scanners. They share one stream of elements

Answer (score 0):

First of all, hasNextInt() returns a boolean object, so you cannot cast it into an Int, this is allowed in c++, but not in java.

Second, did you made a trace of the for loop? I think it will crash on the second loop as you read the scanner that is outside the loop. If the t parameter is greater than 1, that should crash, as when it reads once there is no more ints to read.